# mongo db rest Api returns allways same entry

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, mean-stack

I am working on the development af a MEAN app and I have a curious problem:

I have created an API which allows me to get one single document by id:

```
//Get Single Line
router.get('/lines/:id', function(req, res, next){
    db.lines.findOne(
        { _id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id)},
        function(err, line){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(line);
    });
});
```

Now when I call http://localhost:3000/api/lines/593379eb0cbd3a4efcdc1875 I get what I expect:

```
{"_id":"593379eb0cbd3a4efcdc1875","name":...
```

But, when I move this project to a live Server, when I call http://mydomain/api/lines/593379eb0cbd3a4efcdc1875 I allways get the first document in my collection:

```
{"_id":"59337c480cbd3a4efcdc1876","name":
```

Even if I try some id that does not exist - I allways get only the first document.
I really cant figure out, what the probem here is....

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to debug the code to find whether correct _id passed to the controller and to the query? Recheck the database names and collection names matched with your repository for both local and live environments.

Comment: Thank your for your answer! I have already checked if the correct _id is passed and also both enviroments (dev and live) are connected to the same database. For mee it seems that the findOne function for some reason returns allways the first document in the collection

Comment: how this can be ..? 
I can't find any clue on this. Can you try { '_id': mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id)} . _id inside quotation. Just to try..!!